# Understanding $O_{\mathbb{P}(F)}(d)$ on $\mathbb{P}(F)$ (in local coordinates)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, vector-bundles

Say $F$ is a vector bundle of rank $r+1$ on some scheme $X$ with transition maps (cocycle) $\psi_{ij}$ (with respect to some open cover $U_i, U_j,\ldots, U_k$ of $X$). We denote by $\mathbb{P}(F)$ the associated projective bundle. Locally, 
$$\mathbb{P}(F)|_{U_i}\simeq U_i\times\mathbb{P}^r$$ 
and these local patches are glued together by the same cocycle $\psi_{ij}$.

**I want to understand the line bundles $O_{\mathbb{P}(F)}(d)$ on $\mathbb{P}(F)$.** (i.e. its cocycle and sections)

For simplicity, say $d=-1$. Over $\mathbb{P}^r$, the line bundle $O(-1)$ has cocycle $g_{ij}$ given by $g_{ij}(x)=x_i/x_j$, where $[x]=[x_0,\ldots,x_r]\in\mathbb{P}^r$ are homogeneous coordinates.

Let $V_i=U_i\times\mathbb{P}^r$ denote the local patches of $\mathbb{P}(F)$. Then, locally over $V_i$ we have

$$O_{\mathbb{P}(F)}(-1)|_{V_i} \simeq V_i\times\mathbb{A}^1$$

and we want to find the transition functions $\xi_{ij}$ which give the glueing

$$(V_i\cap V_j)\times \mathbb{A}^1 \to (V_i\cap V_j)\times \mathbb{A}^1$$
$$(p,t) \mapsto (p, \xi_{ij}(p) t)$$

So we have $\xi_{ij} \colon (U_i\cap U_j)\times\mathbb{P}^r \to k^\times$ sending $(u,[x])\mapsto \xi_{ij}(u,[x])$.

**What is the right choice for $\xi_{ij}$?**

My very naive guess would be $\xi_{ij}(u,[x]) = g_{ij}(\psi_{ij}(u)\cdot[x])$. But I guess this is not correct.

I am in fact reading Gathmann's notes of Algebraic Geometry (p.189). He says

> *On the overlaps $U_i\cap U_j$ these line bundles* [ $O_{\mathbb{P}(F)}(d)$ ] *are glued by $\varphi\mapsto\varphi\circ\psi_{ij}$, where $\varphi = \frac{f}{g}$
>   is (locally) a quotient of homogeneous polynomials $f, g \in k[x_1 ,\ldots , x_r]$ with $\deg f − \deg g =
> d$*

I do not clearly understand what it means. And how about sections? I would highly appreciate if somebody could elaborate a bit on this construction.

Comment: $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(F)}(d))=H^0(X, S^dF)$ for all $d$, where by convention, for $d<0$, we let $S^dF=0$. So, in particular, for $d=-1$, you get no (non-zero) sections.

Comment: @Mohan oh I see. How do you show your isomorphism?

Comment: Most books will have it. For example, you may look at Fulton's intersection theory. If $\pi: \mathbb{P}(F)\to X$ is the natural map, $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(F)}(d)=S^dF$.